# Which one is correct: "I haven't been at work in a week" or "I haven't been to work in a week"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me which one is correct: *I haven't been at work in a week* or *I haven't been to work in a week*? For example:

> I haven't been **at**/**to** work in a week, so would you bring me up to speed on what is going on with the project.

Comment: Please see [Avoid using a slash when asking about two versions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4821/91457)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of:

> - (1) I haven't been at work in a week, so would you bring me up to speed on what is going on with the project.
> - (3) I haven't been to work in a week, so would you bring me up to speed on what is going on with the project.

would be grammatically valid, and a fluent speaker might use either form.

I think, without doing any online searches, that the form with *at* (1) is probably more common, at least in the US. The form with *to* (2) is probably more likely when referring to physical presence in the workplace, but either form is still just fine. Shorter phrases with essentially the same meaning will often be used, such as:

> - I've been away this week, so ....
> - I've been out for a while, so ...
> - I've been out sick, so ...
> - I've been gone for a week, so ...
>   < * I've been on Project G for a week, so ...

Answer (score 0):

Those are both correct but mean slightly different things.

"To" could be used to treat it as an abstract activity (like "I haven't been to the movies recently."), or to emphasize the trip (like "I haven't been to Rome in a decade."), or if you're not trying to emphasize anything but are just not currently at the place.

"At" could be used if you want to specifically emphasize the fact that you're at the location. It would also be more common when you're at the place while speaking.